# Ableton: quick calculation of average loudness of a track (without listening to whole track with a meter)

Tags: mixing, ableton-live, vst

I would like to bring all tracks of a session to 0 db because I want to use a analog channel strip simulation simulation, and CLA points out that those sounds best with audio source within that range.
Now I know that I could run every track thru a db meter, but it would take ages, so is there a neet tiny tool (VST/AU or internal) with instant calculation and possibly even automatic compensation?

Thanks

Comment: 0db relative to what? 0dbFS in a DAW workchain is on the edge of clipping.

Comment: you are completely right, I meant the relative 0 of the particular chanel strip emulation. One can look it up for each plug, but never the less there is a sweat spot of the input gain, and I would like to quickly bring all the tracks to this exact position.

Comment: well you need to know what it is bevore that is possible. db by itself is meaningless. If this is on a DAW probably the plugin is designed to work at some level ref FS.

Comment: ok, than let's consider as a rule of the thumb that general safe levels are: RMS around -18 and peaks around -10/-8. What can I do to ensure that each source track does satisfy this requirement quickly? I mean I wish I could somehow normalize the tracks to -18 for example and not 0. But than of course i could use a until with -18 gain before the channel strip and normalize normally, or normalize and bring all tracks down by 18db :)

Comment: (1) run the track, note the peak level, then change the gain to apply correction you want? or (2) export as wav and use external tool like audacity to tell you peak level? just off the top of my head.

Comment: oh, you want to adjust for average level? OK, then you need some plugin to tell you what that is. but average over how long? entire track? 1s? 10s? it matters.

Comment: thanks, but I wanted to avoid going track by track and have a standard procedure to hit the plugs where they like to be hit, and do the mixing afterwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101966/discussion-between-macilias-and-danmcb).

Comment: "normalising to average level" is a weird and somewhat problematic concept. That's why metering audio is quite a complex field, and people spent much time defining what they really mean.

Comment: Two points  - 1, usually in a DAW the channel meters are more a convenience than an absolute - overcooking them will not go into clipping because it all uses floating point internally. 2, run the entire piece top to bottom, most DAWs will show the peak on every meter. Nothing will show the average unless you use a plugin.

Comment: & a late 3. The quick & dirty way to do this would be to actually, literally, normalise all your audio tracks; then you know there's at least one point in every track that does actually hit 0dBFS [I've no idea how to achieve any of this in Ableton, never used it, so can't add as an answer].

Comment: If you have any knowledge of the data format in an "Ableton" file, then load it into your math tool of choice (R, python, MATLAB, etc.) and calculate the statistics of the amplitude data.

Comment: @Tetsujin: thanks that's basically what I also comed up with, just normalizing and than reducing all the tracks by 9db will bring me at least peak wise into the ballpark. Regarding the density (and here also at @Carl-Witthoft) I will probably care less about the average and more about the peak, to give the plug some headroom and hope to be somewhere close to its "sweet spot". At the end there is room for improvement, but its easy to normalize all tracks during the import and also to bring them down a few db, so it should work quickly.